# Datatables sorting by descending

Tags: jquery, sorting, datatables

I'm using datatables 1.10, and have a rather large table that takes a minute or so to load. The table is generally most useful when sorted in descending order, so it's rather annoying to have to sort by (column) ascending, wait, then sort (column) descending. I know there's a way to sort columns descending by default, but I've had little luck implementing it. Here's my table:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
        <table id="reportTable" class="table table-condensed table-hover table-columntoggle display">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th data-searchable="false" data-orderable="false" data-defaultcontent="" class="details-control"></th>
                    <th class="dt-left" data-data="ManufacturerPartNumber">Part Number</th>
                    <th class="dt-left" data-data="ItemName">Item Name</th>
                    <th class="dt-left" data-template="#templateWarehouseName">Warehouse</th>
                    <th class="dt-center" data-data="QuantityTimeBlock1" id="QuantityTimeBlock1Label">Quantity 0 to 45 Days</th>
                    <th class="dt-center" data-data="QuantityTimeBlock2" id="QuantityTimeBlock2Label">Quantity 46 to 90 Days</th>
                    <th class="dt-center" data-data="QuantityTimeBlock3" id="QuantityTimeBlock3Label">Quantity 91+ Days</th>
                    <th class="dt-center" data-data="TotalQuantity">Total Quantity</th>
                    <th class="dt-center" data-data="ValueTimeBlock1" id="ValueTimeBlock1Label">Value 0 to 45 Days</th>
                    <th class="dt-center" data-data="ValueTimeBlock2" id="ValueTimeBlock2Label">Value 46 to 90 Days</th>
                    <th class="dt-center" data-data="ValueTimeBlock3" id="ValueTimeBlock3Label">Value 91+ Days</th>
                    <th class="dt-center" data-data="TotalValue">Total Value</th>
                    <th class="dt-center" data-data="CurrencyType">Currency</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tfoot>
                <tr>
                    <th colspan="4" class = "dt-left">Page Totals:</th>
                    <th class = "dt-left">Total:</th>
                    <th class = "dt-left">Total:</th>
                    <th class = "dt-left">Total:</th>
                    <th class = "dt-left">Total:</th>
                    <th class = "dt-left">Total:</th>
                    <th class = "dt-left">Total:</th>
                    <th class = "dt-left">Total:</th>
                    <th class = "dt-left">Total:</th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
            </tfoot>
            <tbody></tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the related code:

```
    <script>
    $(function() {
        var templateDetails = _.template($('#templateDetails').html(), { variable: 'data' });
        var dataTable = $('#reportTable').abcdDataTable({
            'drawCallback': onDrawDataTable,
            "formSelector": "#InventoryAgingValuationSearch",
            "searching": false,
            "url": "/Reports/InventoryAgingValuation/Search",
            "order": [[1, "desc"]],
            /*"columns": [
                { "defaultContent": "" },
                { "defaultContent": "" },
                { "defaultContent": "" },
                { "defaultContent": "" },
                { "orderSequence": ["desc", "asc"] }, //first sort desc, then asc,
                { "orderSequence": ["desc", "asc"] },
                { "orderSequence": ["desc", "asc"] },
                { "orderSequence": ["desc", "asc"] },
                { "orderSequence": ["desc", "asc"] },
                { "orderSequence": ["desc", "asc"] },
                { "orderSequence": ["asc", "desc"] },
                { "orderSequence": ["desc", "asc"] },
                { "defaultContent": "" }
            ],*/
            "footerCallback": function (row, data, start, end, display) {
                ...
            }
        });
        var tableApi = dataTable.api();

        function onDrawDataTable() {
            $("#reportTable").find('.has-popover').popover();
        }

        $('#reportTable tbody').on('click', 'td.details-control', function() {
            ...

                var newTable = $(row.child()).find('table.NestedItemsTable').abcdDataTable({
                    "searching": false,
                    "url": "/Reports/InventoryAgingValuationItems/Search",
                    "bPaginate": false,
                    "exporting": false,
                    "bInfo": false,
                    "asSorting":  ['desc'],
                    "ajaxData": function(d) {
                        d["WarehouseId"] = warehouseFilter;
                        d["ItemId"] = itemFilter;
                        d["IncludeSerializable"] = includeSerializableFilter;
                        d["IncludeBulk"] = includeBulkFilter;
                        d["ManufacturerPartNumber"] = $('#ManufacturerPartNumber').val();
                        d["ItemName"] = $('#ItemName').val();
                        d["SerialNumber"] = $('#SerialNumber').val();
                        d["OwnedByCompanyId"] = $('#OwnedByCompanyId').val();
                        d["CustomerPurchaseOrderNumber"] = $('#CustomerPurchaseOrderNumber').val();
                        d["AbcdPurchaseOrderNumber"] = $('#AbcdPurchaseOrderNumber').val();
                    },
                    "order": [[1, "desc"]]
                });
            }
        });

        $("#InventoryAgingValuationSearch .btn-group .btn").click(function () {
           ...
        });
    });
</script>
```

The way the code is currently configured, it fails to sort by descending on the first click. My first attempt at this resulted in the commented-out chunk above, in the form of

```
{ "orderSequence": ["desc", "asc"] }, //first sort desc, then asc,
```

Should I uncomment that, I get a datatables error along the lines of "Requested unknown parameter 'x' in row 0. The datatables documentation says this could mean that the  is screwing things up, or that I have too many rows. So far as I can tell, the  in the HTML is unimportant, because it's in the footer. If I remove a row, on the other hand, the page hangs and does not progress beyond 'loading'.

How do I get this working?

Comment: What is `abcdDataTable`? There are no `formSelector` or `url` options. There is comma missing before last item in `columns` array.

Comment: abcdDataTable is a customized datatable we're using throughout the project. The missing comma was from me being sloppy in the deletion of an unnecessary comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I decided to go with the graceless-but-working solution to this issue. Because it seemed unlikely that this was going to work out well on the client side, I changed around the sorting logic on the controller. Instead of

```
case InventoryAgingValuationReportColumnType.ItemName:
                            query2 = orderBy.Item2 == OrderDirection.Ascendant ? query2.OrderBy(x => x.ItemName) : query2.OrderByDescending(x => x.ItemName);
                            break;
```

I now have

```
case InventoryAgingValuationReportColumnType.ItemName:
                            query2 = orderBy.Item2 == OrderDirection.Ascendant ? query2.OrderByDescending(x => x.ItemName) : query2.OrderBy(x => x.ItemName);
                            break;
```

It's not the cleanest way to do it, and doesn't really fix the issues I was having with DataTables, but it's a workaround that's acceptable for the time being.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.js-basic-example').DataTable({
        responsive: true,
        sort: false
    });
```

if you set the list from db in php side. it works only desc list. I did it and done.